# Calling service function from within the same service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call a service method from within the same service but I am getting call to undefined function error. So I made a work around as shown below but still wondering how I can call the service function without using the work around. So can someone please help by telling me what I am missing here? Thanks

```
.factory('TestSvc', function($http, $q) {        
  return {  

     login: function(){

          var checkStatusFunction = this.checkstatus; //This is the workaround to make it work...

          $http({ method:'POST',
                url: url
                responseType: 'json'
          }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
               //this.checkStatus();   //this will return error call to undefined

               checkStatusFunction();  //this will work as it is the work around
          }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){ 
          });

     },
     checkStatus: function(){
     }
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit less hacky would be:

```
var $this = this;
```

Instead of:

```
var checkStatusFunction = this.checkstatus;
```

And then call:

```
$this.checkstatus();
```

Comment: any thoughts why this.function is not working within the $http call?

Comment: The context of "this" changes. Even though you are visually still inside the scope of the service, the callbacks from $http have their own context of "this".  Using Vennik's solution works because you are creating a reference to the variable "this" which gets captured by the $http methods through a closure.

Comment: Exactly wat cgatian is saying.